# Using Google OAuth with React-Django Application

Tags: reactjs, django, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am working on a web application with ReactJs frontend and Django backend. In this app, I will need to send calender notifications to the users and overall need a user authentication feature for which I planned to use google oauth. From react, I am able to log in the user and get the access tokens but since they expire in an hour, I planned to get the authorization code and use it to get the refresh/access tokens from the backend whenever a user logs in/needs to send API request. The issue is that I am not able to find any good resource on how to get refresh tokens from the backend given I have the authorization code. Most of the HTTP based methods I have found are very outdated and I have searched some of the google documentation but have not found anything worthwhile. Since I could not find any package that would handle this, I have been trying to send `POST` request to the URL mentioned here (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_1) but only get a `400` response. Below are 2 methods I have tried.

```
        to_send={'code':user_data['code'], 'client_id': cl_id , 'client_secret': cl_secret, 
        'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:3000/', 'grant_type':'authorization_code'}
        test=requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data=to_send)
        print(test)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path/key.json')
        scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])
        authed_session = AuthorizedSession(scoped_credentials)
        response = authed_session.request('POST', 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data = to_send)
        print(response)
```

Ive also tried other things like creating a flow object.

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file( JSON_PATH, scopes=API_SCOPE)
flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URL
flow.fetch_token(code=user_data['code'])
credentials = flow.credentials
```

where `user_data['code']` is the authorization token and I get the error
`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Bad Request`